# Convert a deprecated .click function to set a variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, initialization, deprecated

I would be grateful if someone can help with converting a deprecated .click function to set a variable to either an 'onClick' state or null.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
for (var x=0; x<buttons.length; x++)
{
    var btn = buttons[x];
            
    var btnClass = btn.btnClass || "btn-primary";
    var btnLabel = btn.label || "Label";
            
    var $btn = $('<button type="button" class="btn ' + btnClass + '" data-dismiss="modal">' + btnLabel + '</button>');
            
    $btn.click(btn.onClick || null);
            
    $(".pf-modal .modal-footer").append($btn);
}
```

The current functionality works, however whilst I have a basic understanding of JavaScript/jQuery, I am unable to modify the deprecated '.click' function into the likes of a trigger event such as $btn.trigger('click', btn.onClick || null);

Comment: Are you looking for `$btn.on("click", btn.onClick || null)`? It's not clear what "buttons" is or where it came from.

Comment: Also `.trigger()` is not for establishing event handlers; it's for *triggering* events.

Comment: `.click` is unlikely to ever be removed.  It got "deprecated" by an over zealous dev and is now stuck there.  There's lots of discussions about it available.

Comment: Your code `$btn.click(btn.onClick || null);` sets up an event *handler* - the equivalent is `$btn.on("click", btn.onClick || null)` (for which `.click()` is a shorthand).   `.trigger` *fires* the event.

Comment: Thank you so much to all for taking the time to respond to my request for help with this issue.  'freedomn-m' guidance to utilise the .trigger event after the setting up of the .click handler has allowed my code to work.